# WooCommerce: Get date when order was refunded

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've checked the WooCommerce documentation to see if there is a date in the refund object which I can read as date when the order was refunded:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Refund.html

The problem is that I can't find anything there and in the web. So is there a way to get something like the refunded date from a WooCommerce order?

So something like:

```
$refunds = $order->get_refunds()
$refunds->refund_date;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed there is a way. `$refunds` is an array as there can be many refunds.

```
// Get order object (eg from id)
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Get all refunds
$refunds = $order->get_refunds();

// Loop over refunds
foreach ($refunds as $refund) {

    // Old way:
    echo $refund->date;

    // New way (see @Yoda’s comment)
    echo $refund->get_date_created()->format( 'd/m/Y' );
}
```

Comment: ```echo $refund->date;``` gives error: **Refund properties should not be accessed directly.** Try instead: ```echo $refund->get_date_created()->format( 'd.m.Y g:i:s' );```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of Christian, I've found another working solution which is a bit more compact. It only works for the first refund but in my situation I've just one refund (so all or nothing). I hope it helps someone sometimes:

```
// Get order object (eg from id)
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Get date from refunds in german date format
echo $order->get_refunds()[0]->get_date_created()->format( 'd.m.Y' );
```